# Angular 2 web app integrating with on-premise ADFS 2.0

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, adfs2.0

The scenario is the following:

- Angular 2 front end hosted on Amazon S3
- ASP.NET Core 2.0 back end services (dockerized and pushed on Amazon ECS)
- On-premise ADFS 2.0 Server

My front end is not build on top of a Visual Studio startup template, the implementation is completely dissociated with the back end.

The architecture is wired up, there is a VPN between my Amazon VPC and the private network of my client and all works smoothly.

Now I need to set up the federated authentication integrating the ADFS 2.0 Server with my web application. I've tried to find a solution for my scenario but the version of the ADFS seems to have a lot of limitations about communication protocols.

I've tried to look up at adal.js library, which I understand is the standard for this kind of integration, but reading through the documentation and the samples I've found only valid implementations with ADFS 3.0 or higher.

Is there a valid implementation of some js library which can communicate whit ADFS 2.0?

Comment: Another option is if your users use corporate office 365, then you could use Azure AD which will communicate with ADFS.

Comment: As far as I know all the other systems used by my users are old native .net applications communicating with that ADFS 2.0 server

Comment: These days, it is not uncommon for corporate users not having office 365 online account, although they might not know it. It means their on-premise AD accounts are already synced to Azure AD. So, the authentication flow is a lot easier than communicating with ADFS directly .

Comment: I'll check that, thank you, but I'm pretty sure that there is no sync with Azure AD or Office 365. Do you know any other possible way to communicate with the ADFS directly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with ADFS 2.0 is that it only supports OAuth WebAPI and not OpenID Connect (which is why all the examples are for ADFS 3.0).

Good example [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) re. the general idea.

And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs) for adal.js for ADFS 3.0.

I don't know of an example for your specific scenario but hopefully, these two links will give you some leads.